# White color substance on the branch of hibiscus plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, hibiscus

I have three hibiscus plants growing in our garden but for one hibiscus I could see some white color substance on the new leaves and branch. Can anyone please advise on how to get rid of this and save this plant as well as it should not spread to other plants. [image][image][image]

Comment: A close-up picture of the "substance" could help us identify it. otherwise, it can be many things, each with a specific cure.

Comment: Sure will post the pics

Comment: Posted few pics. I could also see leaves are eaten by some insects can you please help to find a solution

Comment: Seems not too bad. The damage on the leaf seems to be of different source (caterpillar?); Try to crush them manually, and see if they come back. This worked great for me in case of aphids attacks. But I agree with Sami id: looks like mealy bugs. Difficult to get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

It can be mealy bugs. They are hidden in a white coating that may also have a cottony look. They are pretty common in hibiscus. I heard that insecticidal soap is a good control for mealy bugs.Before you apply anything first identify what you have.